# How to replace a string in all folder and file names

Tags: shell, rename

How can I recursively replace a string in all folders and files' name with a different string? I am running Red Hat 6 and I can find them with:

```
find . -name \*string\*
```

I've managed to do it for strings within files:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' {} +
```

but how could I replace in a similar way all file names?

Comment: how can I replace a string with the mv command? There might be different folders names containing that string. I would need something like "find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' {} +" but for folder names

Comment: On what operating system? Do you have a `rename` command? Is it perl rename?

Comment: `mv` is the final tool. You need to start with `find` + `bash/shell` beforehand

Comment: The command you show (`sed`) doesn't change any file names. It replaces the string *inside the file* but leaves the file name as it was.

Comment: @terdon I'm using red had 6, I have the rename command

Comment: @terdon yes, that's my problem, I've managed to change the string within all the files, but I would like to know how to replace the name of folders and files too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `find` and `rename`:

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/string1/string2/g' {} +
```

The `find . -type f` part of the command means to search for all files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.`).

- The `-exec` option tells `find` to execute a command on each file it finds.
- The `rename` command is used to rename files, and the syntax used here is for the Perl version of `rename`.
- The `'s/string1/string2/g'` is a regular expression that specifies what to search for and what to replace it with. In this case, `string1` is the string to be replaced, and `string2` is the replacement string. The `/g` at the end means to replace all occurrences of `string1` in the filename.
- The `{}` symbol is a placeholder for the filename that `find` has found.
- The `+` at the end of the command tells `find` to pass multiple filenames at once to the rename command, which is more efficient than invoking rename for each individual file.

So, overall, this command searches for all files in the current directory and executes the `rename` command to replace all occurrences of `string1` with `string2` in the filename for each file found.

Comment: This is nice! Please keep in mind that there are some cases with deeper direction structures. For flat directory changes this is fine.

Answer (score 8):

you can replace all the file names using `for` and `mv` command.

here i am replacing all the text files starting with `abc` names with `xyz`

```
for file in abc*.txt; do mv -v "$file" "${file/abc/xyz}"; done
```

the below command will replace the files recursively in all folders

```
for file in `find . -type f -name 'abc*.txt'`; do mv -v "$file" "${file/abc/xyz}"; done
```

Comment: but this doesn't run recursively into folders, right?

Comment: see the edited answer.

Comment: This was perfect. Solved renaming a long list of files where only needed to change one word. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier with `zsh`'s `zmv`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(**/)(*string1*)' '$1${2//string1/string2}'
```

Change to

```
zmv '(**/)(*string1*)(#qD)' '$1${2//string1/string2}'
```

If you also want to rename hidden files or files in hidden directories.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that command. Unfortunately I can only use bash